# How to switch between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app I have three activity as

1. Activity 1
2. Activity 2
3. Activity 3

How to switch between activities.

So how can this be done?

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{   

    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.settingOpt:                           
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsForm.class);
            this.startActivity(intent); 
            this.finish();
        break;         

        case R.id.reminderOpt:                          
            Intent intentR = new Intent(this, ReminderForm.class);
            this.startActivity(intentR);   
        break;

        case R.id.helpOpt:                          
            Intent intentH = new Intent(this, HelpForm.class);
            this.startActivity(intentH);  
            this.finish();
        break;

        case R.id.shareOpt:                             
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Name of the thing to share");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "www.gmail.com");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share LoveCycle's website link with your friends"));
        break;

        default:

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);       
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I click back button from Activity3 I should always went to Activity1,instead of Activity2:

Use following method on back button press event in Activity3:

```
setResult(R.id.common_backToActivity1);
```

And in Activity2 capture that setResult as follows and close this Activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        switch(resultCode){
        case R.id.common_backToActivity1:
            closeActivity();  //Finish Activity2 in this method
            break;  
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Then you will get directly to Activity1.

Comment: what is this R.id.common_backToActivity1 here

Comment: It's integer resultCode. You can directly take any integer constant like setResult(100) and again in onActivityResult() as case 100:

Comment: yeh..i used finish..but onBackpress from activity3 it doesn't call these function onActivityResult()..thats why it is not finish activity2

Comment: hey nik..its working..but if i open activity2 three or four times and then activity3, what happened is when i press backbutton from activity3 it comes to activity2 and it remain in activity2 and exit afer four click of back button.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question

1. use finish() in activity 2 after you call activity 3.
2. you should probably close the application when you hit home button. Because your application will retain it's state until it's closed.

Comment: I have use finish() in onStop() of activity 2 and its work fine but when i am in activity 2 and click home button then also it finish my activity thats why when i start the app it show activity 1.So where i write this finish()

Comment: just after you call the activity 3. startActivity(this, Activity3.class);

Comment: Actually i have call all these activity using optionMenu

Comment: i don't think it will do anything different if you are using options menu, you must be calling activity 3 from somewhere, just put finish() , after that, it will work.

Comment: yeh its working but if i open activit1 from option menu, then activity2 from optionmenu then activity3 from optionMenu.After that if i click back button from activity 3 it exit the app instead of going to activity 1

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Home Key
```

You can not control the behaviour of Home key. When Home key is pressed your app is sent to background and when you launch your app again then it comes to the state from where you have left. But this behaviour is not consistent as it is device dependent. Device can `finish()` your app if it needs memory or any resource which your app is using.

```
for your activity:
```

start activity 3 with [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivityForResult) and on back press `finish()` activity 3 and when you get the call in `onActivityResult()` in activity 2 `finish()` it there and you will be back to activity 1.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question. You could override your back button and check which activity you are currently in and handle where to go based on that.

To your second question.

Put `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in your startup activity in the manifest file. That will make your application always start over when you relaunch it.

Comment: clearTaskOnLaunch works only when the activity is launched from launcher but not from recent task lists (long press of home key).

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your Intent calls to follow this. Rather than moving from Activity 2 to Activity 3, you should have Activity 2 finish and return some value that prompts Activity 1 to then call Activity 3. As for when you press home, add the same code to your OnResume() OnCreate() areas so that it knows which intent/Activity to always load.

Comment: can you please help me with an example