# Activity lifecycle issues

Tags: android

I have 3 activities running ,navigating a1 to a2 then a2 to a3.Now pressing back button from emulator,I want to go to the activity a1 without finishing activity a2.How can i do this..Please guide me..Thanks in advance

Comment: Please refereed below link It may be help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790248/how-to-finish-activity-from-another-activity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can override that back button

```
public void onBackPressed() {

 Intent start = new Intent(currentclassname.this,which activity u want.class);
    startActivity(start);
    finishActivity(0);
 }
```

By this you can move on any activity. This is very easy and simple way

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your A3 activity's back key event:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,A1.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: he wants the activity a2 not to be finished. Will the above solution (FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) not remove a2 from the stack. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: @Deva then i think he should use SINGLE_TOP.

Answer (score 1):

Write this thing in a3

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),a1.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity 2 does not have to die. Just implement the onPause() and onResume() methods o hold and restore the activity state.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

The life cycle diagram is helpful. To control he way activities are generated and moved on he stack you can adjust the manifest activity properties or add flags to the calling intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement this from your AndroidManifest.xml file, just adding android:noHistory="true" attribute in those  you want.

Answer (score 0):

In a2 activity

you can overide the restart() as below::

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onRestart();
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),a1.class));
}
```