# How to destroy previous activity in Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, destroy, activity-finish

I have four activity, i.e. A, B, C and D. A launches B, B launches C, C launches D. When C is launching D, I want to destroy the activity B depending on the situation(logic for that will remain in activity C) so that when I go back From D, it will follow D->C->A path. So I want to destroy activity B from C. How it is possible?

Comment: you can get your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972097/activity-lifecycle-issues)!

Comment: take a reference of activity B to C and call ref.finish(); where ref is the reference to the B activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finish Activity B when you are calling Activity C depends on your logic.
For example

```
if(true){
Intent in = new Intent(B.this,c.class);
startActivity(c);
}
else
{
Intent in = new Intent(B.this,c.class);
startActivity(c);
finish();
}
```

Comment: I want to finish B when I am calling D from C, not to finish B from B itself. Finishing B from B itself is not even a beginner's question.

Comment: Ok then you can call startActivityForResult(in,5); to start Activity C. and implement the override method in Activity B like     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    { super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      if(resultCode==0){ finish(); }else{}
    }  
And set the resultcode in Activity when you are calling Activity D like Intent backintent = getIntent();
                setResult(0);                
                Intent in = new Intent(C.this,D.class);            
                startActivity(in);
Thats it

Answer (score 1):

finishActivity(requestCode);

this method may help you..

What to do is start the activity C with the some **request code** from B... and accordingly finish the activity with this request code

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `finish();` in activity **B's** `onActivityResult` when returning from **C** depending on the logic you want

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is that you can register a broadcast in each class and whenever you want to finish sendbroadcast and finish that activity.

```
        // REGISTER IN ONCREATE
        BroadcastReceiver form_filled = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String received_action = intent.getAction();

                if (received_action.equals("finish_a")) {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(form_filled, new IntentFilter("finish_a"));

        // THIS YOU HAVE TO DO WHEN YOU WANT TO FINISH
        Intent temp_intent = new Intent();
        temp_intent.setAction("finish_a");
        sendBroadcast(temp_intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok then you can call startActivityForResult(in,5); to start Activity C. and implement the override method in Activity B like

```
 @Override 
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)       {                
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent); 
    if(resultCode==0)
    { 
      finish(); 
    }
    else
   {

    } 
    }
```

And set the resultcode in Activity when you are calling Activity D like

```
Intent backintent = getIntent(); 
  setResult(0); 
  Intent in = new Intent(C.this,D.class); 
  startActivity(in);
```

Thats it....