# Restoring original activity as it is (like home button) when back button pressed

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-homebutton

I am designing android application using tabHost.

TabActivity is always being launched from anther activity( suppose, Activity A). After that Activity A has no use.

When I am on tabActivity & if back button is pressed, then all goes in background( like every app). Now using task manager when I start app again, I want to retain tabActivity as it was. (like home button.) But currently I am getting Activity A. (as with back Button activities are getting destroyed.)

In short, I want to override backButton similar to Home Button.

I tried without luck with moveTaskToBack(true).

Can anybody suggest solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/android-override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button

Answer (score 0):

Also you could try this which should make the back button into a home button.

@Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)); 
}

Comment: @sooti8 thnx for taking interest. Problem is similar to home key, i want to hide app. App is not getting hiding without super.onBackPressed(). Any idea?

Comment: Try this. Destroy your Activity A using Finish() once you change activities.

Comment: as with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479965/how-to-destroy-previous-activity-in-activity

Comment: thnx again man. Finishing approach is working. But cant restore all tab.

Comment: as those are dynamic not any fixed tabs.